# TAOCP: Section 1.2.4 -> Q 23: An example to show the law is not correct

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> **Question**: Give an example to show that Law D is not always true if $r$ is not relatively prime to $s$.
>
> **Law D**: If $r \perp s$, then $a \equiv b$ (modulo $rs$) if and only if $a \equiv b$ (module $r$) and $a \equiv b$ (modulo $s$).

Where $r, s, a, b$ are integers.

Suppose you have chosen numbers for $r$ and $s$, now let's say $a = krs + c$, for some integer $k$ and $c$.

Now we know $a \equiv c$ (modulo $rs$).

As $krs$ is multiple of $r$ and $s$ both, which implies

$a \equiv c$ (modulo $r$) and $a \equiv c$ (modulo $s$)

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: I was talking about your spelling: T-A-O-C-P. Never heard it called "T-O-A-C-P" before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One direction holds with no assumption on $r$ and $s$:

> If $a\equiv b\pmod{rs}$ then $a\equiv b\pmod{r}$ and $a\equiv b\pmod{s}$

So if property D fails for $r$ and $s$ non coprime, you should be able to find *particular* values of $r$, $s$, $a$ and $b$ so that

1. $a\equiv b\pmod{r}$
2. $a\equiv b\pmod{s}$
3. $a\not\equiv b\pmod{rs}$

Can you find suitable $a$ and $b$ for $r=s=2$?

Comment: Suppose $a = 2$ and $b = 2$ then
$2 \equiv 0$ (mod $r$),
$2 \equiv 0$ (mod $s$) and
$2 \equiv 2$ (mod $rs$), but as it is $\equiv$, we can choose $b$ for the  $2 \equiv 0$ (mod $r$) and $2 \equiv 0$ (mod $s$) as $2$. Can't we ?

Comment: @Abhisek You're on the right track, but $a=2$ is good, whereas $b=2$ isn't: why not $b=0$, which is what you're actually using?

Comment: The $\equiv$ relation confused me($b = 2 \equiv 0 = b`$). We need to make sure the relation should satisfy for every $b$) not just one. Got it thanks